# Owl Carousel Slider jamming in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am having trouble getting my Owl Carousel Slider to work properly on a website that I made on this site... [Justin Kim](http://www.justindkim.com)

I have adjusted all of the photos so that they would not have to resize and slow down the speed of the site. This site works great on chrome, IE and mobile browsers. I have added the

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;  // added this
}
```

fix and this has still not helped with my issue. I have also looked at the dev tools and unable to come up with why this is happening.

Comment: The slider loads and then stops. It seems like it keeps making a ton of requests to somewhere.